# How to sort DataTable by two columns in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, datatable

I have a `DataTable` that looks like below;

```
|              ID                    | ItemIndex |   ItemValue
ce895bd9-9a92-44bd-8d79-986f991154a9     1            3
ae7d714e-a457-41a8-8bb4-b5a0471c3d2f     2            2
a774dff3-acc0-4f50-a211-a775e28dcae3     2            1
292bbd50-290b-4511-9e4e-2e74e3ebe273     3            2
ae7d714e-a457-41a8-8bb3-b5a0471c3d22     3            1
```

I want to sort this table by `ItemIndex` first, then sort the sorted table by `ItemValue`.

How can I achieve this?

Edit: after sorting, I want my table like below;

```
|              ID                    | ItemIndex |   ItemValue
ce895bd9-9a92-44bd-8d79-986f991154a9     1            3
a774dff3-acc0-4f50-a211-a775e28dcae3     2            1
ae7d714e-a457-41a8-8bb4-b5a0471c3d2f     2            2
ae7d714e-a457-41a8-8bb3-b5a0471c3d22     3            1
292bbd50-290b-4511-9e4e-2e74e3ebe273     3            2
```

Comment: How can I group table and sort each item seperately?

Comment: `DataView dv = new DataView(dt);`
`dv.Sort = "ItemIndex, ItemValue"`;`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to DataSet/DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx)

```
var newDataTable = yourtable.AsEnumerable()
                   .OrderBy(r=> r.Field<int>("ItemIndex"))
                   .ThenBy(r=> r.Field<int>("ItemValue"))  
                   .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Do we now have two DataTable objects?

Comment: @DOK, yes but the result can be assigned back to original DataTable.

Comment: How can I group table and sort each item seperately?

Answer (score 32):

Create a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) and use the Sort Property:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.Sort = "ItemIndex, ItemValue";
```

e.g.

```
foreach (DataRowView row in dv) {
   Console.WriteLine(" {0} \t {1}", row["ItemIndex"], row["ItemValue"]);
}
```

For more information, check out MDSN for a more thorough example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx

Comment: Short and sweet, doesn't create another (potentially large) object, and this code is highly readable, if slightly less sexy than using Linq.

Comment: thanks, it's working great also. But I didn't understand whether dt is sorted table after dv.Sort.

Comment: @George  - Hi, this is working for string columns, but i have a column say ColA. with string values 1.23, 11.45 and 2.34, as these are string values your way of sorting will have not effect on them. I am stuck here what should i do?

Comment: @user612644 I realize this is an old comment to an even older answer. Your problem appears to be the age old "How to sort numbers stored as strings?" problem. That is a completely different problem of a completely different scope.

Answer (score 25):

On the datatable object, just get the defaultview object and set the sort.

```
dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "ItemIndex, ItemValue";
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer so far and works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: For clarification: You still need to either call dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable() in order to actually perform the sort and copy the (sorted) rows to a new DataTable, or you can iterate the dataTable.DefaultView. But you can't simply apply the .Sort property and then iterate the rows of the original dataTable and expect them to be in sorted order.

Comment: ToTable() does not need to be called for data binding. I believe Default view is used internally.

Answer (score 12):

By creating dataview

```
var dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
dataView.Sort = "ItemIndex ASC, ItemValue ASC"
```

Here dataTable is table you want to sort

Comment: Would have posted the same thing!  Reference on MSDN:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use that

```
DataView oDataSet;
oDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "Column1 ASC ";
```

Comment: How would we go about doing that with multiple columns? Please check the question title.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take, given the helpful comments of others here.

```
DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);//datatable to dataview
dataView.Sort = "columnName1 ASC, columnName2 DESC";//string that contains the column name  followed by "ASC" (ascending) or "DESC" (descending)
dataTable = dataView.ToTable();//push the chages back to the datatable
```

Comment: you deserve more than 1 thumbs up!!!. this was the ONLY solution that worked for me.
I purposely set the original querys to have different sorts. EVERY other method the rows were not always in the desired order. this one was perfect!!! (sorted on 12 columns)
I was comparing two datasets to see if the rows were the same. The purpose was to see if a stored proc change had messed up the data.
THIS DESERVES MORE VOTES!!!! THank you !!! .ToTable() rocks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
_UserAuditTrailTable.DefaultView.Sort = sortExpression;
```