# Sorting asp.net gridview control based on row level c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

My issue is related to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752266/how-to-merge-multiple-columns-values-into-one-column-asp-net-gridview-c-sharp/37755710?noredirect=1) on stackoverflow.
In my previous question I needed to merge columns with the same values in a c# asp.net Gridview Control. This problem was resolved by the excellent help and support from other stackoverflowers, however I'm also required to sort the order on row level e.g:

**Current format:** 
[image]

The gridview control allows me to sort values by columns (top to bottom) however would there be a way to sort the rows, e.g: left to right on row level, if you take a look at the (Current format) screenshot and check row 3, you will see the following result: ( 2a, 2c, 2x2a, 2c ) Now ideally I would like to group these together as in ( 3x2a, 2x2c ), but not sure if this would be the correct approach as it would involve shifting the whole column, and I could imagine that if we sort the first row correctly and go to the second row, we might mess up the first row result again, not sure if this would work or even possible.

I would like to have my gridview control displaying the data as following:

**Required format:**
[image]

1. Would this be the approach or achievable in a asp.net gridview control?
2. How would I be able to achieve the ideal solution otherwise?

If you need any additional information, please ask and i will try to expand my question.

> **UPDATED INFORMATION:**

After **ConnersFan's** suggestion, I got the following result, the idea is sort of there, but not quite yet.

**After running the page i get this screenshots, after each screenshot i will explain what happens:**

[image]
^^^ **DEFAULT PAGE LOAD:** This merges/groups the equal values in the row cell together.

[image] 
^^^ **After clicking on the first row 'sort' link**, the first row looks correct, the column header and values are all moving to the correct place.

[image]
^^^ **After clicking on the second row 'sort' link**, it sorts the second row correctly and has not messed up the first row

[image]
^^^ **After clicking on the third row 'sort' link**, it messes up the first and second row, but managed to merge and group the third row ok.

[image]
^^^ **After clicking on the fourth row 'sort' link**, it messes up the first, second and third row, but managed to merge and group the fourth row ok.

[image]
^^^ **After clicking on the fifth row 'sort' link**, (which should not make a difference as they are all the same equal value, it messes up the first, second, third and fourth row, but managed to merge and group the fifth row still ok.

[image]
^^^ **After clicking on the sixth row 'sort' link**, (which should not make a difference as they are all different values, it messes the rest up.

So, what i would love to see is that, we dont need to sort these with a button but just on page load all rows are correctly merged and grouped, without messing up the previous row and we should end up, if done correctly, with the required format screenshot, so the order of the columns is determined by the values in the row cells, if they are equal.

Thank you guys ever so much, you have helped me out greatly already.

Comment: Is this correct: you need to have the rows sorted so they can be grouped properly via the GridView grouping logic?

Comment: hi fnostro, that's sort off what i am looking for indeed, however my ideal solution would be that by default/rendering (without clicking the 'sort' button of ConnorsFan solution) all rows would be sorted and would not move the previous row cells, so: in my head it would be something like, sort row1 (equal values are being merged and columns re-positioned) then row2 (equal values are being merged and columns re-positioned, without messing up row one, etc etc for all rows) so that the table eventually would look like the "required format" schreenshot

Comment: I don't understand the required format. Only Row 3 is sorted in that image.

Comment: ok, i think the misunderstanding is in the sorting part, say: the values of row 3 are: ( 2, 4, 2, 3, 2 ) I would like to see all the 2's grouped and merged together over those columns, in which order this would be does not matter, so its not really sorting as in ASC or DESC but grouping them so for example ( 4, 222, 3) or ( 3, 4, 222 ) or ( 222, 4, 3 ) as long as all the columns are keeping there values in place and the previous rows are not messed up, in the required format image, you will see that the rows are correctly grouped and merged, the column position could be totally random.

Comment: Can you show what you expect for the following data: Row 1: 1a 2a 1a 2a 1a 2a, Row 2: 1a 1a 1a 2a 2a 2a, Row 3: 1a 1a 2a 2a 1a 1a

Comment: yes, i see what your saying i cant, i tried to print out the table and cut the columns, so i would be able to move them manually infront of me, however in this case it does not seem possible to match them up, could this be an indication of a wrong approach for my desired outcome ? would you recommend it doing it a different way?

Comment: The equivalent request, in traditional column sorting, would be to sort according to "all columns", which does not make sense. In order to sort, you have to pick a column (or a few in a specific order), and reorder the rows according to that sort column. The same principle applies to your case for the transposed sort: you must pick a sort row, as suggested in my answer (or impose that the first row is the sort row). In any case, you can use the code from my answer and experiment with it.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, and i will expiriment with your provided code, if i have found a solution to this i will update my question or reply with an answer, once again thank you for your time and help, for now i have marked your answer as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to transpose the usual sort command, so that it rearranges the GridView columns according to the order in a row rather than rearranging the rows according to the order in a column.

You can insert a LinkButton in the first column to trigger the sort on a specific row (I used a TemplateField instead of a ButtonField in order to set the text with a binding expression):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# "Row " + ((Container as GridViewRow).RowIndex + 1) %>' CommandName="SortRow" CommandArgument='<%# (Container as GridViewRow).RowIndex %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In code-behind, you can define the number of fixed columns at the left of the grid, and a `sortRowIndex` variable which is set in the `RowCommand` event handler:

```
private const int fixedColumnCount = 1; // Row number column
private int sortRowIndex = -1;

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "SortRow")
    {
        sortRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        // Here set the data source and bind the data to the GridView
        GridView1.DataSource = ...
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The sort itself could be performed in the data source, as suggested by fnostro in your previous post. Since I don't know what the data looks like, here is one way to do it in the grid.

The work can be done in the `PreRender` or in the `DataBound` event of the GridView. The code to group the cells with the same content, given in [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752266/how-to-merge-multiple-columns-values-into-one-column-asp-net-gridview-c-sharp/37755710?noredirect=1), should be moved in this event handler as well, and placed after the sort operations.

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> sortedColIndexes = null;

    if (sortRowIndex >= 0)
    {
        // Gather the cell data on the sorted row...
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> cellsToSort = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        sortedColIndexes = new List<int>();

        GridViewRow sortedRow = GridView1.Rows[sortRowIndex];
        for (int i = fixedColumnCount; i < sortedRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            TableCell cell = sortedRow.Cells[i];
            cellsToSort.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(cell.Text, i));
        }

        // ... and sort the cell indexes according to the cell content
        sortedColIndexes = cellsToSort.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
    }

    RearrangeRowCells(GridView1.HeaderRow, sortedColIndexes);

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        RearrangeRowCells(row, sortedColIndexes);

        // The code below is taken from the other post
        // It merges the cells with the same content
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            TableCell cell = row.Cells[i];

            if (cell.Visible)
            {
                int colSpanValue = 1;

                for (int j = i + 1; j < row.Cells.Count; j++)
                {
                    TableCell otherCell = row.Cells[j];

                    if (otherCell.Text == cell.Text)
                    {
                        colSpanValue++;
                        otherCell.Visible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (colSpanValue > 1)
                {
                    cell.ColumnSpan = colSpanValue;
                    cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Beige;
                    cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Utility function which performs the cell permutations on a given row
private void RearrangeRowCells(GridViewRow row, List<int> sortedColIndexes)
{
    if (sortedColIndexes != null)
    {
        List<TableCell> sortedCells = new List<TableCell>();

        foreach (int cellIndex in sortedColIndexes)
        {
            sortedCells.Add(row.Cells[cellIndex]);
        }

        for (int i = fixedColumnCount; i < sortedCells.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            row.Cells.Remove(sortedCells[i]);
            row.Cells.AddAt(i + fixedColumnCount, sortedCells[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ConnersFan, this is sort off what i am looking for indeed, however my ideal solution would be that by default/rendering (without clicking the 'sort' button) all rows would be sorted and would not move the previous row cells, so: in my head it would be something like, sort row1 (equal values are being merged and columns re-positioned) then row2 (equal values are being merged and columns re-positioned, without messing up row one, etc etc for all rows) so that the table eventually would look like the "required format" schreenshot

Comment: So, you want each row to be sorted without affecting the other rows? In the image of the "required format", I see only Row 3 being sorted. The other rows, including the header, seem to have adapted to the condition set by Row 3. Given my code sample above, you could process the rows as you want by moving the code to the `RowDataBound` event.

Comment: Hi ConnersFan, thank you for your help, i have update mu original question.